# How to tell if a sqlite column is AUTOINCREMENT?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I’m using a sqlite database, and i wanna know if a specific column is AUTOINCREMENT or NOT

I’ve tried

```
PRAGMA table_info('table name') ;
```

But it gives me only  ID,  NAME, TYPE, PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL, and DEFAULT VALUE

Answer (score 8):

Querying with

```
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(yourtable);
```

you can get the primary key column name.

To check whether it is an autoincrement column, check whether the table has an autoincrement sequence:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='yourtable';
```

Interpretation:

- If the count came out as non-zero, the table has an autoincrement primary key column.
- If the count came out as zero, the table is either empty and has never contained data, or does not have an autoincrement primary key column.

Although the [SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) seems to imply that the sqlite_sequence table is populated  when the table is created in fact this is not the case and the count only becomes available after data is inserted.

Comment: Shouldn't there always be an entry in the sqlite_sequence if a table has an autoincrement primary key column?

Comment: This is convenient but you should be aware that it isn't bullet-proof. Consider the situation where the table was created, the column is autoincrement and primary key -- but the table does not yet have any records. In this case, relying on COUNT to determine whether the column is autoincrement will lead one astray...

Comment: @Lara is correct in that if the primary key in the CREATE statement contains the keywords PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT then there will always be an entry in the sqlite_sequence table so for that case you can expect it to be deterministic if the count(*) is non-zero. http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Apologies to @laalto for my edit, his original statement was correct and have reverted the interpretation.

Comment: So sad, there is actually no way to tell.. for an empty table.

Answer (score 8):

Forgive me, for I have sinned:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  a AS (
    SELECT name, lower(replace(replace(sql, char(13), ' '), char(10), ' ')) AS sql
    FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE lower(sql) LIKE '%integer% autoincrement%'
  ),
  b AS (
    SELECT name, trim(substr(sql, instr(sql, '(') + 1)) AS sql
    FROM a
  ),
  c AS (
    SELECT b.name, sql, '' AS col
    FROM b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      c.name, 
      trim(substr(c.sql, ifnull(nullif(instr(c.sql, ','), 0), instr(c.sql, ')')) + 1)) AS sql, 
      trim(substr(c.sql, 1, ifnull(nullif(instr(c.sql, ','), 0), instr(c.sql, ')')) - 1)) AS col
    FROM c JOIN b ON c.name = b.name
    WHERE c.sql != ''
  ),
  d AS (
    SELECT name, substr(col, 1, instr(col, ' ') - 1) AS col
    FROM c
    WHERE col LIKE '%autoincrement%'
  )
SELECT name, col  
FROM d
ORDER BY name, col;
```

This query is based on two assumptions:

1. The `autoincrement` flag is present on your column definition inside of `sqlite_master`
2. The column is of type `integer` (as currently required by SQLite)

Since regular expressions are not available out of the box, this query uses a recursive approach to match all the columns. Please, forgive me.

#### Of course...

You can also simply process your `sqlite_master.sql` content in some client, e.g. a Java program, using simple regexes, if that's easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread from sam and sine in this post [See Thread](https://stopbyte.com/t/how-to-check-if-a-column-is-autoincrement-primary-key-or-not-in-sqlite/174/2)

*SQLite AUTOINCREMENT can only be applied to PRIMARY KEY’s*

Based on this logic you can use

```
SELECT "is-autoincrement" FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name="<your-table-name>" AND sql LIKE "%AUTOINCREMENT%"
```

as mentioned in the thread.
It worked for me. Not sure of its reliability though.